# google.payments.inapp.buy fails in a Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, android-pay

The call to `google.payments.inapp.buy` fails for some people in my google chrome extension.

It pops up new window and try to show the payment window, however, it shows a message saying that in-app payment is not available at the moment.

It doesn't give me information about why and how it failed so I don't know where I start from.

It is also fact that it works for other people, and for myself when I test.

Does anybody know if there are conditions (like google wallet account setting) the user have to meet in order to successfully open the in-app payment window?

Comment: Self discovered that apparently Chrome sometimes confuse the account Chrome itself is signed in, and account I signed in within a tab. If try after you disconnect your Chrome from account, it pops up Chrome sign in page instead of payment page, and it just works after logging in for some reasons.